# How to capture a Grid to image file with different size?

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0

In a WPF application, what's the preferable way to do such a thing ?
If I have a grid of 1000 x 1000 size, how can I save it as an image with 200 x 200 size for example ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified my answer below a bit so it would work for this scenario
[Slice Large WPF Canvas Into Many Small PNG Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453059/slice-large-wpf-canvas-into-many-small-png-images)

Call it like this

```
SaveFrameworkElementToPng(myGrid, 200, 200, "MyImage.png");
```

*SaveFrameworkElementToPng*

```
private void SaveFrameworkElementToPng(FrameworkElement frameworkElement,
                                       int width,
                                       int height,
                                       string filePath)
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = VisualToBitmapImage(frameworkElement);
    SaveImage(bitmapImage, width, height, filePath);
}

public BitmapImage VisualToBitmapImage(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)frameworkElement.ActualWidth,
                                                    (int)frameworkElement.ActualHeight,
                                                    96d,
                                                    96d,
                                                    PixelFormats.Default);
    rtb.Render(frameworkElement);

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
    encoder.Save(stream);

    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();

    return bitmapImage;
}

public void SaveImage(BitmapImage sourceImage,
                        int width,
                        int height,
                        string filePath)
{
    TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
    ScaleTransform scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
    scaleTransform.ScaleX = (double)width / sourceImage.PixelWidth;
    scaleTransform.ScaleY = (double)height / sourceImage.PixelHeight;
    transformGroup.Children.Add(scaleTransform);

    DrawingVisual vis = new DrawingVisual();
    DrawingContext cont = vis.RenderOpen();
    cont.PushTransform(transformGroup);
    cont.DrawImage(sourceImage, new Rect(new Size(sourceImage.PixelWidth, sourceImage.PixelHeight)));
    cont.Close();

    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
    rtb.Render(vis);

    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        encoder.Save(stream);
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Samir Sabri: Any luck with my suggestion? Or did I missunderstand your question?

Comment: Yes, it worked, but, its slow when performance is concerned, Thanks Meleak

Comment: @Samir Sabri: Ok, I never really checked the performance of it. Tried it now and it seems to be able to save a simple `Grid` with 4 rows 100 times in about a second. I guess it depends on what you need it for.

Comment: What's the size of the Grid you've tested with please ?

Comment: It was the default size. I increased it to 1000x1000 and it took about 8 seconds. What's your results?

Comment: we have pages with size of 1280x1024, its too slow as my team reported, but, they didn't measure the time ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12376/discussion-between-meleak-and-samir-sabri)